# Crashlytics and iPhone XS

Tags: iphone, crashlytics

Is anyone else who uses crashlytics having problems with using the beta feature of Crashlytics on iPhone XS/Max? It’s saying that I need to upload a build that supports my devices architecture (armv6), but the iPhone XS has an armv8.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We're looking into issues using Beta with the latest iPhones.